# Getting help on two functions with the same name in two different packages

Tags: r, package

I know how to use two functions with the same name in two different packages, like `packageName:::functionName`. But  `help(packageName:::functionName)` does not work even though `?packageName:::functionName`. This is strange to me. Any thoughts.

```
library(plyr)
library(reshape)

plyr:::rename
reshape:::rename

help(plyr:::rename)
?plyr:::rename
```

Comment: `help("rename","plyr")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read `help(help)`. You can use `help(rename, plyr)` to get the documentation for `plyr::rename`.