# Redefining help_console function to get help on function from a given package

Tags: r, package

Following is the function to get help on R functions. See below:

```
help_console <-
function (topic, format = c("text", "html", "latex", "Rd"), lines = NULL,
    before = NULL, after = NULL)
{
    format = match.arg(format)
    if (!is.character(topic))
        topic <- deparse(substitute(topic))
    helpfile = utils:::.getHelpFile(help(topic))
    hs <- capture.output(switch(format, text = tools:::Rd2txt(helpfile),
        html = tools:::Rd2HTML(helpfile), latex = tools:::Rd2latex(helpfile),
        Rd = tools:::prepare_Rd(helpfile)))
    if (!is.null(lines))
        hs <- hs[lines]
    hs <- c(before, hs, after)
    cat(hs, sep = "\n")
    invisible(hs)
}

help_console(topic="lm", format = "text", lines=1)
Fitting Linear Models
```

Now I want to redefine this function to get help on R function from given package. Here is my MWE

```
help_console2 <-
function (topic, pkg, format = c("text", "html", "latex", "Rd"), lines = NULL,
    before = NULL, after = NULL)
{
    format = match.arg(format)
    if (!is.character(topic))
        topic <- deparse(substitute(topic))
    if (!is.character(pkg))
        topic <- deparse(substitute(pkg))
    helpfile = utils:::.getHelpFile(help(pkg, topic))
    hs <- capture.output(switch(format, text = tools:::Rd2txt(helpfile),
        html = tools:::Rd2HTML(helpfile), latex = tools:::Rd2latex(helpfile),
        Rd = tools:::prepare_Rd(helpfile)))
    if (!is.null(lines))
        hs <- hs[lines]
    hs <- c(before, hs, after)
    cat(hs, sep = "\n")
    invisible(hs)
}

help_console2(topic="lm", pkg="stats", format = "text", lines=1)

Error in find.package(if (is.null(package)) loadedNamespaces() else package,  : 
  there is no package called ‘topic’
```

This function is throwing error.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: I must be missing something: what's wrong with `help(package:function)` ?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft `help(package::function)` not working. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26223338/707145).

Comment: @MYaseen208 thanks -- I'd forgotten the syntax rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong argument order and need to outsmart non-standard evaluation:

```
help_console2 <-
  function (topic, pkg, format = c("text", "html", "latex", "Rd"), lines = NULL,
            before = NULL, after = NULL)
  {
    format = match.arg(format)
    if (!is.character(topic))
      topic <- deparse(substitute(topic))
    if (!is.character(pkg))
      topic <- deparse(substitute(pkg))
    helpfile = utils:::.getHelpFile(do.call(help, list(topic=topic, package=pkg)))
    hs <- capture.output(switch(format, text = tools:::Rd2txt(helpfile),
                                html = tools:::Rd2HTML(helpfile), latex = tools:::Rd2latex(helpfile),
                                Rd = tools:::prepare_Rd(helpfile)))
    if (!is.null(lines))
      hs <- hs[lines]
    hs <- c(before, hs, after)
    cat(hs, sep = "\n")
    invisible(hs)
  }

help_console2(topic="lm", pkg="stats", format = "text", lines=1)
#Fitting Linear Models
```